# Magento 2 : How to get swatch attribute label

Tags: magento2, attributes, swatches

I have an attribute "brand" with type Swatch.

I have created many brands as an option in this attribute.

I want to filter brands label which are starts with a particular letter (ex. A or B or C).

Answer (score 0):

Well, I am using manufacturer as a brand so in my case.

Make Magento_catalog->templates->product->view->brand_info.phtml and
put that code.

```
<?php
$_helper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');
$_product = $block->getProduct();

$_code = $block->getAtCode();
$_className = $block->getCssClass();
$_attributeLabel = $block->getAtLabel();
$_attributeType = $block->getAtType();
$_attributeAddAttribute = $block->getAddAttribute();

if ($_attributeLabel && $_attributeLabel == 'default') {
$_attributeLabel = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute($_code)->getFrontendLabel();
}

$_attributeValue =$_product->getResource()->getAttribute($_code)->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
?>
<?php if ($_attributeValue): ?>
<div class="product_<?php echo $_className?>"><?php if ($_attributeLabel != 'none'): ?><h4 class="brand" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Brand">Brand:&nbsp;</h4><?php endif; ?><div class="brand-value" itemprop="brand"<?php echo $_attributeAddAttribute;?>><h4>&nbsp;<?php echo $_attributeValue; ?></h4></div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>

<style>
    .brand{
        /*color:#D00000;*/
        float:left;
        margin:0;
    }
    .brand-value{
        color:#008000;
    }



</style>
```

then make a layout in Magento_catalog->layout->catalog_product_view.xml
put that code according to your attribute name.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
    <referenceContainer name="product.info.price">
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.brand" template="product/view/brand_info.phtml" before="-">
        <arguments>
        <argument name="at_call" xsi:type="string">getBrand</argument>
        <argument name="at_code" xsi:type="string">manufacturer2</argument>
        <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">brand</argument>
        <argument name="at_label" xsi:type="string">default</argument>
        <argument name="add_attribute" xsi:type="string">itemprop="manufacturer2"</argument>
        </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: I am not asking for products. I have separate page In which all the brands (attribute) are display but suppose customer wants to see brands which name is starts from A then he needs to click on letter (A-Z) and I will display all the brand list which are starts from A letter.